# Selenium grid not able to get it working

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I've executed the following hub and node commands in my windows command prompts.  I can see this is working as I get the grid console when browsing http://localhost:4441/grid/console

```
C:\seleniumserver\java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -port 4441

C:\seleniumserver\java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.ja -role wd -hub http://localhost:4441/grid/register
```

My automation code has the following C# code.

**C# code snippet**

```
var capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
capabilities.Platform = Platform.CurrentPlatform;
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

When I run run the automation I get the following error message

**Error message received**

```
An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds.
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong please?  First time setting this up

Many thanks,

**Update after comments**

made the following change

```
        var capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
        capabilities.Platform = Platform.CurrentPlatform;
        IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4441/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Error message

at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) at myfile.ctor() in C:\Projects\UAT Automation\myfile.cs:line 43 at ....ctor() in C:\Projects\UAT Automation...cs:line 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting your hub in the port `4441` but you are trying to connect to `4444` using

`IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);`

Please change your instantiation code to

`IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4441/wd/hub"), capabilities);`

and try again.

Comment: i get an error, i've added the error message into my question, see "update after comments section"

Comment: shall I try a different version of selenium?

Comment: Do you know if your chromedriver is available in your PATH of the machine wherein your node is running ? Did you take a look at the logs of the node to see what you see ? Btw, please accept my answer, since it answered your original question of facing `Connection timeout` problems.

Comment: to check the path is that my personal path or the system path?

Comment: I am referring to the PATH variable. Not sure what do you mean by personal path or system path

Comment: within the environment variables dialog i have two PATHS, one for "user variable for me" and another for "system variables" - not sure which one to update with "C:\chromedriver.exe"

Comment: Most often updating User level PATH variables is easy. It doesnt matter which one you update. To be on the safer side, please do reboot the machine as well (If things dont work)

Comment: ok thanks, and then to test the change in the command prompt i can just type "chromedriver" I assume?

Comment: Yes. Also make sure you type the command `chromedriver` from a command prompt by switching to some other directory. Another quick way would be to open up a command prompt and type `echo %PATH%` and check whether in the output you see the directory which contains the `chromedriver` binary.

Comment: I'll create a new question to focus on this new problem.  many thanks